# filtering files for query databricks taking too long

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have three datasets which join them together with unionAll command. Those datasets are already computed(with count() command) and persisted. The new dataset that i'm generating by unioning those three keeps stucked in 'Filtering files for query' for hours. Since those datasets are already in disk and memory, why it is take so long to filter files? I'm using databricks with 3 workers and 1 main worker, each worker has 14GB of ram and running on pyspark.

Comment: Can you put your code here as well?

Comment: can you share the code responsible for this issue, also the type and size of the data, maybe also the physical plan (.explain())

Comment: what is the file format used?